# How can I use CQL in Cassandra 3 to determine if a table uses compact storage?

Tags: cassandra, cql3

If I use the `cqlsh` tool that comes with Cassandra 3, it can tell me if a table was created `WITH COMPACT STORAGE`. All I have to do is `describe table_name;` and it shows me the CQL used to create the table.

The `describe` functionality is a feature of `cqlsh`, not of the CQL language. I need to determine if a table uses compact storage using just CQL. What do I need to query in the `system_schema` to determine if a table is using compact storage?

Comment: In cassandra > 3.0 compact storage is just a place holder and means nothing. They updated the storage engine and now everything is compact.

Comment: That's incorrect. Using compact storage places many restrictions on what can be done with the table.

Comment: check http://datastax.com/2015/12/storage-engine-30 and  http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8099. "In fact a table will have the exact same internal layout whether is uses COMPACT STORAGE or not, so there will be no impact at all on the size on disk.". It doesn't make any difference at all other than limiting what you can do.

Comment: If you read your employer's own documentation you'll find it clearly places limitations around primary keys: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCompactStorage.html

Comment: Maybe because it includes the 2.2 version which still had compact storage but its a little out of date. After 3.0 the restrictions are there on creation/alters, but they are superficial since there is no difference inbetween compact and non compact tables. I opened a ticket to update the docs, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of the `TableMetadataV3` class in the cassandra driver for python, the logic for determining compact storage is as follows

```
 flags = row.get('flags', set())
            if flags:
                compact_static = False
                table_meta.is_compact_storage = 'dense' in flags or 'super' in flags or 'compound' not in flags
                is_dense = 'dense' in flags
            else:
                compact_static = True
                table_meta.is_compact_storage = True
                is_dense = False
```

The `row` object is a dictionary that is the result of the query `"SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables"`

So to determine if a table uses compact storage, the following steps are necessary.

1. Use CQL to query `Select flags from system_schema.tables where keyspace_name=? and table_name=?`. Substitute the keyspace and table in as parameters
2. If flags is empty, then the table uses compact storage.
3. If flags is present with 'dense' or 'super' as members of the set then the table uses compact storage.
4. If 'compound' is not in the set then the table uses compact storage.
5. Otherwise the table does not use compact storage.